# wix toolset - expected values for ManagedRuntimeVersion / ManagedPipelineMode

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an MSI using the [WiX toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/). I have a couple questions:

1. In the WebAppPool documentry there are two Properties: `ManagedRuntimeVersion` and `ManagedPipelineMode`. What are the expected values for them?
2. The documentation mentions that they can be set using formatted Property. What are these Properties?

I'll highly appreciate a sample.

Answer (score 0):

`ManagedRuntimeVersion` refers to the version of .NET the app pool should use (e.g. `v4.0`)
`ManagedPipelineMode` refers to the pipeline mode the app pool should run in (e.g. `integrated`)

Formatted properties just means you can set the values using the name of a `Property` ([wix docs](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_property.htm)) instead of specifying the value inline

Comment: Thank you Rob,
For the ManagedRuntimeVersion what are the valid values(enum)?

Comment: That's a good question, I can't find a definitive list anywhere. I know that "v1.1" "v2.0" "v4.0" and "v4.5" all work... I would guess that "v3.0" and "v3.5" will also work.